# Chrome extension: Get content of downloaded file

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, google-chrome-extension, local

is there a option to get the content of an local (downloaded) pdf file, that is opened in google chrome?

last years it works so:

User open pdf file with google chrome. Then he clicks my extension in chrome browser.
My extension "downloaded" the local pdf file to chrome downloads folder.
Then my extension reads the content of the downloaded file via HTTPRequest

```html
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
 
 var pdfblob = (this.response); 

};
```

...but now since about 5 days, this will not work anymore. I get this error:

GET file:///C:/Users/Standard/Downloads/test.pdf net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Knows someone a solution for this problem?
Perhaps i can read the files content while the file gets downloaded?

Thomas

UPDATE
With this Code i try at the moment:

```html
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'file:///C:/Users/Standard/GoogleDrive/Dropbox/FLIESENLEGER.pdf', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
 
 var pdfblob = (this.response); 

    console.log(pdfblob);


};
```

manifest.json:

```html
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

  "manifest_version": 2,


"permissions": [
"activeTab",
"file://*",
"http://www.pdfzorro.com/",
"https://www.pdfzorro.com/",
"https://www.google.com/",
"downloads",
"file://*"
],


  "name": "Save to Google Drive™",
  "version": "0.0.0.20",
  "short_name": "Save to a folder on Google Drive™",
  "description": "Save PDF, images or webpages - opened in Chrome -  to your Google Drive™. You can select a folder where the file should be saved.",
  "icons": { "16": "logo16.png",
          "128": "logo.png" },  
  

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }

  
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to have an option where the client can download a pdf file that you have stored in your directory?

Comment: Yes, this im doing. The client downloads a local pdf file to chromes download folder. But since a few days (perhaps chrome update?) the httprequest to get a blob of the pdf file in the download folder do not work anymore.

Comment: Hey @ThomasMühlbauer, did you get it working again? Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable access to file URLs in your extension and also add the `file:///` permission in the manifest file.

Add to manifest.json

```
{
  "permissions": [
    // other permissions
    "file:///"
  ]
}
```

Go to `chrome://extensions/`, click on the extension details button and check the `Allow access to file URLs` option.

You'll have to warn your extension users to check this option!

[image]

In addition to this, you can use [chrome.downloads](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) to get information about downloaded files, such as filepath, size, etc.

Comment: in permissions i have file:/// allowed, but it do not work.
The file path i take from chrome.download, this works. But i always get this error since a few days:

popup.js:271 GET file:///C:/Users/Standard/Downloads/FLIESENLEGER.pdf net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Did you check the `Allow access to file URLs` option?

Comment: yes, access file urls in chome browser is also activated for my extension

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the popup.js code?

Comment: p.s. when i copy an pdf file to my extension folder, for example test.pdf, and i give my function the url "test.pdf" .. then it works.. this means, my extension has only local access to the chrome extension folder... but not to the download folder of google chrome...

Comment: You have "file://*" in your permissions, but it's "file:///". Fix this and try again. I think my answer is correct for this one

Comment: with "file:///" same error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Maybe it's because of the colon in the C drive notation. Try to create the url with a escaped colon file:///C%3A/Users/ or with double backslashes file:///C:\\Users\\.

Comment: is this the reason why XMLHttpReuest for local files do not more work? https://www.golem.de/news/sicherheitsupdate-chrome-schwachstelle-wird-aktiv-genutzt-1903-139833.html

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirements and manage to read the downloaded files using fetch in background.js. I got CORS error in ContentScript.js. Make sure you have file://* permission in manifest file.

```
function getLatestDownloadBlob(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch("File://" + filename)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        resolve(response.blob());
    })
    .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
    });            
  });
}
```